# What is the meaning of this regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a regex defined follow to match `http urls`, anyone can help to explain in English?

```
^/foo/.*(?<!\.css|\.js|\.jpg)$
```

Comment: Looks like it is intended to match any URL of the form "/foo/*.css" OR "/foo/*.js" OR "/foo/*.jpg".

Comment: That's not a URL, it's just a path.

Comment: @EJK to match all other forms except these. It's a NEGATIVE look behind.

Comment: @AndyLester - I know it's just a path, but I said URL because the question explicitly indicated that the context was "http urls"

Comment: That's not a valid Perl regex.

Comment: @ikegami: Sure it is: `$url =~ m#^/foo/.*(?<!\.css|\.js|\.jpg)$#` is valid Perl. It is just unusual to use anything but slashes for terminators (which is the case where `m` operator is assumed)

Comment: @pst: Who cares. It works in Perl, OP asked about Perl. My weapon of preference is Oniguruma anyway, so meh. :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any file or directory in directory `/foo` or below that is not `css`, `js` or `jpg` file.

```
^        start of string anchor
/foo/    literal "/foo/"
.*       any number of characters
(?<!...) match from here backwards must fail:
  \.     dot
  css    literal "css"
  |      or
$        end of string anchor
```

So, start of string, `/foo/`, maybe some other characters, then string ends - but just before, can't be `.css`, `.js` or `.jpg`.

EDIT: Apologies for being stubborn. It is indeed an invalid regular expression for most engines, including Perl. The reason is, negative lookbehind must have fixed width; and this lookbehind can be either four characters (in case of `.jpg` or `.css`) or three characters (`.js`). A fix is to insert an additional "match anything" into the lookbehind so that the width is always four:

```
^/foo/.*(?<!\.css|.\.js|\.jpg)$
```

With that, it works:

```
perl -e 'print "/foo/bar" =~ m[^/foo/.*(?<!\.css|.\.js|\.jpg)$];'
=> 1
```

OP: Your problem with regexpal.com is the fact that they test for JavaScript regular expressions, which do not implement negative lookbehind at all. Regexp dialects differ in details.

Comment: in the directory tree under /foo/* i think

Comment: @radai: You're right, it wasn't clear as I wrote it.

Comment: I can't get match in [regexpal](http://regexpal.com)

Comment: One might try using [rxrx](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp::Debugger) though!

Answer (score 4):

Your pattern is meant to match the same as the the following:

```
m{^/foo/} && !m{\.(?:css|js|jpg)\z}
```

This is so much more readable that I don't need to explain it. It also has the advantage of actually compiling, unlike your pattern.

```
>perl -c -e"m{^/foo/.*(?<!\.css|\.js|\.jpg)$}"
Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/^/foo/.*(?<!\.css|\.js|\.jpg)$/ at -e line 1.
```

Comment: It is a valid regexp, just like `don't` is a valid string. If you want to make a Perl *literal* of it, you might have to select a proper way to do it: `"don't"` is a good choice, as is `'don\'t'` (completely parallel to `m[/foo/]` and `/\/foo\//`). The fact that language syntax constrains literals has no bearing on validity of the value itself. Meanwhile, `//foo//` is an invalid regexp *literal*, and `*.` is an invalid *regexp*.

Comment: I do apologise, it is indeed an invalid regular expression. Just for not the reasons everyone said.

Answer (score 3):

It matches any string that

1. Begins with a `/foo/`
2. Followed by anything
3. Does not end with either of `.css`, `.js` or `.jpg`

So it matches any file rooted under the directory `foo` (directly or as a subdirectory) that is not a CSS, JS or a JPG.

Answer (score 2):

Learn Regex using `YAPE::Regex::Explain`. Check below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;
my $regex = '^/foo/.*(?<!\.css|\.js|\.jpg)$';
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new($regex)->explain();
```

OUTPUT:

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^/foo/.*(?<!\.css|\.js|\.jpg)$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /foo/                    '/foo/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    css                      'css'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    js                       'js'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    jpg                      'jpg'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```